# Trying to find the density of a random varaible

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be uniform on $(- \pi , \pi ) $. Put $Y = \sin ( X + \theta ) $. Goal: Find density of $Y$

My plan :

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y ) = P( \sin( X + \theta) \leq y ) = P( X + \theta \leq \arcsin y ) \leq P(X \leq \theta + \arcsin y) = F_X(\theta + \arcsin y)$$

But, how can I compute $F_X(\theta + \arcsin y ) $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.

You asked to find the **density**, and $f_X(\arcsin(y)-\theta) = \frac 1 {2\pi}$, because it's a uniform distribution over $(-\pi;\pi)$

However, since $\sin()$ is not properly invertable, there will be two $x$ values in the interval that contribute (equally in this case) to each $y$ value.   So the transformation is:

$$\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = \frac 1\pi \left\lvert \frac{\operatorname d (\arcsin(y)-\theta)}{\mathrm d y\qquad\qquad\qquad\!}\right\rvert 
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac 1 {\pi \sqrt{1-y^2}} \;\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(y)
\end{align}$$

Then if you want the cumulative distribution function, it's obviously:

$$F_Y(y) = \int_0^y f_Y(t)\operatorname d t = \frac{\arcsin (y)}{\pi}\;\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(y) + \mathbf 1_{(1;\infty)}(y)$$